# Member functions vs static functions with object reference

Tags: c++, function, static, member

Why would I use a member function when I can pass a static function a reference to an object?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Widget{
private:
    int foo;
public:
    Widget(){
        foo = 0;
    }
    static void increment( Widget &w ){
        w.foo++;
        std::cout << w.foo << std::endl;
    }
};

class Gadget{
private:
    int foo;
public:
    Gadget(){
        foo = 0;
    }
    void increment(){
        foo++;
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    Widget *w = new Widget();
    Widget::increment( *w );

    Gadget *g = new Gadget();
    g->increment();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this more than a stylistic thing? My understanding is that member functions are created per object instance, while static functions are not -- and since you can make static functions operate on a per instance basis like in the above example, shouldn't it slightly more efficient to create static functions instead of member functions?

Comment: you cannot have virtual static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memeber functions are are not created by instance. They have an implicit first parameter which is the `this` pointer, so they actually look quite similar to your static function.

For example,

```
struct Foo {
  void foo(int i) {}
}

Foo f;
f.foo(42);
Foo::foo(f, 42);
```

the two last lines do the same. However, it is hard to see how one could implement this with static methods or functions:

```
struct IFoo {
  virtual foo() const {}
};

struct Foo1 : virtual public IFoo {
  virtual foo() const {}
};

IFoo* f = new Foo1;
f->foo();
```

So, besides the syntactic sugar of allowing you to call the methods on an instance with the `.` operator, you need them for this kind of run-time polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, only the local variables are per instance when the method is called. The *code* is not duplicated, as juanchopanza says.

Answer (score 2):

It's important because it allows [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming); specifically because it's needed for [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch), where the method to which to bind the call is determined at runtime by the true type of the object on which it's invoked. A static call always binds to the method on the nominated type, regardless of the runtime type of the object itself.